# Adding a method to a Serializable class has any impact on the serialized object's size?

Tags: java, android, sockets, serializable

This is for an Android app in which I need to send the Serializable object ( also known as BallPackage) via Bluetooth to another device.

Since this is done a lot of times, the object's size kinda maters. Of course I could easily move the methods to another class, but it would just feel more "organized" if they were on the BallPackage class.

Bottom line is, I am worried that adding methods to a Serializable class/object, will increase its Serialized counterpart, also increasing the package size sent via socket. Is this really a problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Serialized data does not contain code.